# Is it possible to change dropdown arrow in asp.net which supports in all browsers with out using select tag?

Tags: css, asp.net

i have applied css to a class in asp.net for dropdown control to change dropdown arrow it works fine in chrome and firefox but not in IE. Is there any solution? pls suggest me if so.

```
 <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlServiceArea" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" style="width:100%; height:40px;color:rgb(35,53,110) !important;" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlServiceArea_SelectedIndexChanged" class="ddltextboxborder ddlStyle haysBlueColor dropdownArrowCol">
                                    </asp:DropDownList>
.dropdownArrowCol {
     color: darkblue;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance:none;
  -o-appearance:none;
   appearance:none; 
    background: url("../images/dropdownArrow.png");
    background-position: right;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: Which version of IE you are using, it works fine in 10 and 11

Comment: This may help? https://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/background-image-position-wrong-in-ie-no-problem-other-browsers/